# Tensorflow CPU (normal in python interactive shell, but coredump when run script)

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-interactive

I'm trying to learn Tensorflow on Single CPU mode. When I try to run some examples , such as `[mnist_softmax.py]` it seems that the whole code run correctly and output the expected answer, but shows `[Segmentation fault (core dumped)]` and generate a 1.7G or even bigger core file in the end.
When I run the same code in python interactive shell, it runs well and won't appear such `Segmentation fault.`

And my `Tensorflow` version is `('v1.0.0-65-g4763edf-dirty', '1.0.1')`

Comment: a look at the code might help others to answer

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py

Comment: It's the example on the tensorflow.org [MNIST For ML Beginners].

Comment: I don't know if this problem correlates with sess = tf.InteractiveSession(), but after I comment the script from here to the end, there'll be no core dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change line 61 from `sess = tf.InteractiveSession()`
to `sess = tf.Session()`
and rerun it on the command line.

**replace from line 61 to 72 with this**

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
  # Train
  for _ in range(1000):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

  # Test trained model
  correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
  accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
  print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images,
                                      y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

Comment: The command line script is not an interactive session, and therein lies your problem.

Comment: it hints that [ValueError: Cannot execute operation using `run()`: No default session is registered. Use `with sess.as_default():` or pass an explicit session to `run(session=sess)]'if I change InteractiveSession() to Session directly

Comment: And I try to use [with tf.Session() as sess:] instead of InteractiveSession() to cover the last code.  But it still gives me Segmentation fault at the end.

Comment: @AcAhe I'm not sure what change you've made specifically.  I have though updated the solution I posted with the exact change I am recomending.  If this doesn't work can you send a link to the full code that you tried that includes my changes?

Comment: the code link is above. and here's the output after I run this code.
https://github.com/acahesky/4Debug/blob/master/output.txt

Comment: I'm running tensorflow version 1.0.1 also.  I downloaded your code and ran it locally and it exited fine.  Interestingly I did get all the warnings and output you got **other than** *W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.*

Comment: Here is a link to a help page that describes how to address the SSE3 instructions : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7693

Comment: @AcAhe if this answers your original question then please mark this as the accepted answer.